# Querystring to display data from a table using a global variable in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, global-variables, query-string

I have a global variable that holds the selected value of a drop down list in another webform to be used to display the matching information in the table.

I have tried rewriting the code several times, looking at similar work I've done, looked for answers online.

Here is the code to pass the drop down list value to the global variable on the other web form:

```
{
    Response.Redirect("MemberHome.aspx?EMail= " + DropDownListEmail.SelectedValue);
}
```

Here in the form load I create the global variable for the webform:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Email = Request.QueryString["EMail"]; 
}
```

Here is the SQL statement I've made, it doesn't displays 00 when I run and select a value:

```
SELECT EMail, FirstName
FROM Members WHERE (EMail = @Email)
```

Displaying the selected email and name is the expected outcome but the first email and name in the table is displayed.

Comment: Step through with your debugger and see what value is going wrong where? The code you have shown all looks correct, but somewhere along the way something is going wrong. Only can work that out.

Comment: @DaleBurrell i ended up deleting the form since i got mad and regretted it for a while but i cluttered the solution with connections and it just didnt seem to work well, i ended starting a new project and now got it all working how i wanted to, thank you for confirming my code was correct it was driving me crazy